# Why is the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null showing even though the id are the same in <span> and js?

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror, innerhtml

HTML:

```
<span id=“customer-name”> customer </span>
```

[image]

Js:

```
var customerName = "Harry";
document.getElementById("customer-name").innerHTML = customerName;
```

Comment: `“customer-name”` has curly quotes

Comment: Replace the "smart quotes" with the "simple" double quotes. If that doesn't help, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element).

Comment: you need to paste the HTML as well so we can see the full picture. Where is the Javascript in relation to the HTML? Is it before it?

Comment: @mplungjan How is that? Those curly quotes are parsed as a part of the ID in HTML, see a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ugwLpkh4/1/).

Comment: @Teemu You are cheating `document.getElementById('“things”');`

Comment: @mplungjan No, not cheating, the fiddle points out, that the curly quotes are parsed as a part of the id attribute value (as I translated your (now removed) comment somehow so, that you said "curly quotes don't cause problems").

Comment: OP is NOT using `document.getElementById('“customer-name”').innerHTML = customerName;` so the code will fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy-pasted your code directly, then it is because of the funky "smart quotes" that you have in the HTML. This might be something your editor does automatically and that you want to turn off when writing code.

Corrected:

```html
<span id="customer-name"> CUSTOMER </span>
```

Comment: Please do not answer `typo-type` questions since the question cannot be deleted. In this case the typo was in the question only and not in the actual code

Comment: Thank youu so much !! It worked phew. I couldn't see any mistakes but it was showing error.

Comment: @mplungjan I can't see how you could know that it was not the issue. Using the wrong quotes does lead to the error, and OP just confirmed it fixed the error…

Comment: And I already answered that as a comment when I voted to close as dupe or typo

Comment: @LeeWillis It is not worth having this question answered. There are dupes and it is a typo-type question. I could not agree with myself which to choose when closing and OP cannot delete answered questions. Nothing to do with being keen to vote down

Comment: I am just a beginner in js. We had an assignment where we needed follow steps and the content was asked to copy for that section. Thank you for your precious help and time.